# Mongoose is not populating the fields in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

When I run the following code, I get the object along with the populated fields logged on the console.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRNsi.png)

But, the fields have not been populated in the books collection. Can someone please help me figure this out?

```
const bookSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  genre: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "genre" },
  author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "author" },
  numberInStock: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  rating: Number,
  yearPublished: Number,
  dateAdded: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  liked: { type: Boolean, default: false },
});
const genreSchema = new Schema({ name: String });
const authorSchema = new Schema({ name: String });

const Book = model("book", bookSchema);
const Genre = model("genre", genreSchema);
const Author = model("author", authorSchema);

const books = [
  {
    title: "Sapiens",
    genre: "632873144b0bbfc10ae1942d",
    author: "632873e706fe265eaee77de3",
    numberInStock: 6,
    rating: 4.4,
    yearPublished: 2011,
  },
];

async function saveBook(b) {
  let book = new Book(b);
  book
    .save()
    .then((result) => {
      populateBook(result._id);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log("Error: ", err));
}

function populateBook(id) {
  Book.findById(id)
    .populate("genre")
    .populate("author")
    .exec((err, book) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error: ", err);
        return;
      }
      console.log(book);
    });
}

books.forEach((b) => {
  saveBook(b);
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"the fields have not been populated in the books collection"_? The image (please don't use images!) is showing that population is working just fine, the `name` properties of the author and genre are inserted into the document.

Comment: @robertklep. Yes, the logged object shows that the author and genre have been populated. But when I check mongoDB, the 'books' collection does not have genre and author populated.

It still appears as ObjectID:
genre:632873144b0bbfc10ae1942d
author:632873e706fe265eaee77de3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how population works, it only stores references to other documents in the database. At query time, and if you ask for it (using `.populate()`), Mongoose will retrieve the referenced documents and insert them into the "parent" document.

If you want the referenced documents to be stored in the database, you can't use population but have to use [subdocuments](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html).

However, this will limit the flexibility of your database, because if for example an author name needs to be changed, you need to change all the Book documents in your database to update the author's name. With population, you only need to change the Author document.